# OnsenUI + React + cordova の使用について

Tags: monaca, cordova, reactjs, redux

現在、Monaca CLIを使用してOnsenUI + React + reduxで開発を進めています。
そこで質問なのですが、React上でCordovaプラグインを使用するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
ひとまず端末情報を表示しようと思い、npmにて「cordova-plugin-device」を取得し、
http://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/device/
を参考にReactのコード上で
console.log(device.version)
など実行してみましたが案の定、未定義といって怒られてしまいます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/83518

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

まず、実際の端末(Android, iOS)でないとうまく動作しません。
monaca serveなどのブラウザ検証ではdevicereadyのイベントが発火しませんでした。
Rippleなどを使用する必要があります。
monaca debugなどで実機端末だと問題なく使用できました。